# What is the difference between a wizard and a magician?

Tags: roverandom

In *Tales from the Perilous Realm* there is a story of *Roverandom*, where the dog Rover is cursed by the ***wizard*** *Artaxerxes*, he eventually meets *The Man in the Moon* who is described as the greatest of all ***magicians***. It is said Wizards and Magicians keep an eye on each other and are not the best of friends socially.

Is there an explanation of the difference between a wizard and a magician in this work?

Comment: About £9.50 an hour.

Answer (score -1):

At the request of **Orangedog** I have modified my reply to only have opinions backed by quotes from an official tolkien book. (Sorry if you don't believe his ideas go across his novels, I do).

https://timedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/the_letters_of_j.rrtolkien.pdf

Firstly I want to point out that you will not get a 100% proven answer, but on page 191 (of pdf, 142nd letter).

**The Lord of the Rings is of course a fundamentally religious and Catholic work; unconsciously so at first, but consciously in the revision. That is why I have not put in, or have cut out, practically all references to anything like 'religion', to cults or practices, in the imaginary world.**

This is why he has never really gone into GREAT detail about Wizards and Magicians, they are considered either religious or culty (or even occult I guess he was referring to).

Wizards use knoledge to there ends and have used it to do research, manoeuvre events, industrialise and shine light things, depending on the side the wizard is on.

Magicians on the other hand use racial or lore taught methods of far seeing, shape shifting and protection spells/wards. Dwarves, Men and Elves can use magic they learn, whereas a wizard is inherently gifted.

**Nowhere is the place or nature of 'the Wizards' made fully explicit. Their name, as related to Wise, is an Englishing of their Elvish name, and is used throughout as utterly distinct from Sorcerer or Magician.**

And final quote supporting my above statements.

**Though a skin-changer and no doubt a bit of a magician, Beorn was a Man**

That is implying he was a man, but had knowledge or lore gained to enable him to shape-shift. Like a Magician.

But like Tolkien said, he had to remove allot of the detail because of religious constraints (see first quote).

*My personal opinion that I cannot backup with quotes is that Wizards are put there by the gods and all the 'lesser' peoples have to resort to learning lore and magic from there own culture or from a Wizard.*

Comment: Any sources for this?

Comment: The Lord of the Rings

Comment: But this is about _Roverandom_, unrelated to any Middle Earth mythology. A character called "Tom Bombadil" is the only connection. I'm also pretty sure that magicians never appear in LOTR, so that cannot be your source.

Comment: Unrelated by being written by same guy?

Comment: Are you going to claim Chitty Chitty Bang Bang, the BFG and Charlie and the Chocolate Factory all have a shared mythology?

Comment: Yes they do have the same.

Comment: All of Dauls novels are about emotionally abused kids who escape the evils of industrial England by interacting with none human intelligences whom teach the kids about themselves so they can grow into happy adults. Which novel does not have this mythos?

The metaphors change and there are dozens of names for 'magicians' in Lord of he Rings, he just didn't want to over-use the term 'magic'.

You have elven, ranger, dwarven and dark magic, so many magicians it would of been silly to call them all magicians - he wrote his own languages because he didn't want to bore with repetition.

Comment: That is your opinion, which is not the same as a textually-supported statement.

Comment: (Danny Champion of the World, The Gremlins) or how about Ian Fleming's works? Chitty-Chitty-Bang-Bang (again) and Casino Royale say? You can't explain features of one using (vague, unspported) references to another.

Comment: That is your opinion which is not the same as a textually supported statement.

Comment: See "Marginal-Bad Answer" here: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/4734/13024

Comment: Is it ok to post links on this site?

Comment: It is encouraged, and you should also quote appropriately.

Comment: Alright I found a better answer than my first one in 'The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien' 

https://timedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/the_letters_of_j.rrtolkien.pdf

Page 176

"Nowhere is the place or nature of 'the Wizards' made fully explicit. Their name, as related to Wise, is an Englishing of their Elvish name, and is used throughout as utterly distinct from Sorcerer or Magician. "

He also calls the bear man from 'The Hobbit' a bit of a Magician, because he is a shape shifter.

Comment: But I think my first answer is still a better one, I think you are going to get better answers on questions about Tolkiens minds from fans who have read that stuff a hundred times than any quote he would make himself about magic,  as magic is always a cryptic and hidden art in any great work you have to do a little thinking yourself.

It is easy to find quotes and sources and add your opinion on top but what about coming up with your own opinions? I think it a very narrow mind you have unfortunately. We are here to discuss novels, not debate text, that would just give people half answers.

Comment: That is laughably false. Tolkien is almost unique in the fast amount of information we have, written by him personally, explaining his works. We are not here to conduct original research or indulge in speculation, but to ask and answer questions that can have definitive answers.

Comment: I don't know how I can change your mind on this but tolkien himself said;

“‘The Lord Of The Rings’ Is Of Course A Fundamentally Religious And Catholic Work; Unconsciously So At First, But Consciously In The Revision,” Tolkien Wrote In A Letter In 1953 To Robert Murray, A Jesuit Priest. “That Is Why I Have Not Put In, Or Have Cut Out Practically All References To Anything Like ‘Religion,’ To Cults Or Practices, In The Imaginary World. For The Religious Element Is Absorbed Into The Story And Symbolism.”  
— Jrr Tolkein, Letter (1953) To Fra. Robert Murray, S.J.

Comment: If you have answers put them in the answer. I will still downvote if there's no evidence that they have anything to do with Roverandom.